# Errors in StoreLoad implementation in Hazelcast 3.5 with Scala

Tags: scala, hazelcast

I am using `Hazelcast 3.5` with `Scala`

I am new to Hazelcast and i am trying to write a sample StoreLoad implementation for one of my classes just to check that my callbacks get invoked but i am getting errors

here is my storeload implementation for my class

```
    class AbcStoreLoad extends MapStore[Int, Abc] with MapLoader[Int, Abc] with  MapLoaderLifecycleSupport {



 override def load(id : Int): Abc = {
   println("id is " + id )
   new Abc
 }

     override def loadAll(idList : List[Int]): Map[Int ,Abc] = {
      val abcMap : Map[ Int , Abc] = Map()
      abcMap
    }

  override def loadAllKeys(): Set[Int] = {
  val keySet : Set[Int] = Set()
  keySet
}


   override def destroy() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      println( "------------")

   }


  def init(hcast : HazelcastInstance,prop : java.util.Properties, agrs: String): Unit = {

  }


 override  def delete(id : Int): Unit = {

}

   override  def deleteAll(keySet : Set[Int]): Unit = {

   }


   override  def store ( uuid : Int, abc : Abc){
    println("object with uuid as a key is stored in the Hcast Map")
    println("object id : " + uuid)
  }

   override def storeAll(x1: Map[Int , Abc]): Unit = {

  }


   def close() = {
      println( "------------")


   }


}
```

when i compile this code i get following errors

```
[error] /home/ahsen/scalaworkspace/hcastserver/src/main/scala/AbcStoreLoad.scala:34: overriding method loadAllKeys in trait MapLoader of type ()Iterable[Int];
[error]  method loadAllKeys has incompatible type
[error]   override def loadAllKeys(): Set[Int] = {
[error]                ^
[error] /home/ahsen/scalaworkspace/hcastserver/src/main/scala/AbcStoreLoad.scala:10: class AbcStoreLoad needs to be abstract, since:
[error] it has 3 unimplemented members.
[error] /** As seen from class AbcStoreLoad, the missing signatures are as follows.
[error]  *  For convenience, these are usable as stub implementations.
[error]  */
[error]   // Members declared in com.hazelcast.core.MapLoader
[error]   def loadAll(x$1: java.util.Collection[Int]): java.util.Map[Int,Abc] = ???
[error]   
[error]   // Members declared in com.hazelcast.core.MapStore
[error]   def deleteAll(x$1: java.util.Collection[Int]): Unit = ???
[error]   def storeAll(x$1: java.util.Map[Int,Abc]): Unit = ???
[error] class AbcStoreLoad extends MapStore[Int, Abc] with MapLoader[Int, Abc] with  MapLoaderLifecycleSupport {
[error]       ^
[error] /home/ahsen/scalaworkspace/hcastserver/src/main/scala/AbcStoreLoad.scala:29: method loadAll overrides nothing.
[error] Note: the super classes of class AbcStoreLoad contain the following, non final members named loadAll:
[error] def loadAll(x$1: java.util.Collection[Int]): java.util.Map[Int,Abc]
[error]      override def loadAll(idList : List[Int]): Map[Int ,Abc] = {
[error]                   ^
[error] /home/ahsen/scalaworkspace/hcastserver/src/main/scala/AbcStoreLoad.scala:64: method deleteAll overrides nothing.
[error] Note: the super classes of class AbcStoreLoad contain the following, non final members named deleteAll:
[error] def deleteAll(x$1: java.util.Collection[Int]): Unit
[error]    override  def deleteAll(keySet : Set[Int]): Unit = {
[error]                  ^
[error] /home/ahsen/scalaworkspace/hcastserver/src/main/scala/AbcStoreLoad.scala:74: method storeAll overrides nothing.
[error] Note: the super classes of class AbcStoreLoad contain the following, non final members named storeAll:
[error] def storeAll(x$1: java.util.Map[Int,Abc]): Unit
[error]    override def storeAll(x$1: Map[Int , Abc]): Unit = {
[error]                 ^
```

please guide me whats wrong with my code

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the types `List`, `Map`, and `Set`, which are Scala collection types. To use the Java types, as the interface requires, either add `import java.util._` or import them individually.